# Bootstrap 3, retina displays and col-lg

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, col

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3 and have two different column settings on a div:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-centered">
```

I set up the `col-lg-8` for large desktop screens and would like `col-md-10` for medium screens and laptops. My issue is that when using a retina macbook 13", a large screen is detected due to the high resolution and the wrong column class is applied.

How do I fix this so that `col-md-10` is used on a retina macbook?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely going to have to customize and download a suitable version of Bootstrap 3.3.4 where you modify the media query breakpoints to encompass the correct resolutions. Right now, Bootstrap's breakpoints are defined as:

```
@screen-xs: 480px;
@screen-sm: 720px;
@screen-md: 992px;
@screen-lg: 1200px;
```

If you visit http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints, you can customize these values so they fit your Macbook correctly.